# Finding an upperbound for outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, upper-lower-bounds, positive-semidefinite

I have a vector $x = [y^\intercal_1, y^\intercal_2, \dots, y^\intercal_n]^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}^d$, where $y_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1}, \dots, y_n \in \mathbb{R}^{d_n}$ are column vectors. I want to find an upper bound for the outer product $x x^\intercal$ in the following sense: find a matrix $B$ such that

$$x x^\intercal = \begin{bmatrix}  y_1 y_1^\intercal & \dots y_1 y_n^\intercal\\
\vdots & \quad \vdots\\
y_n y_1^\intercal & \dots y_n y_n^\intercal\end{bmatrix} \preceq B,$$
which means that $B - xx^\intercal$ is positive semi-definite. Are there general methods for finding such bounds? I know that I cannot construct $B$ by simply bounding each element of $xx^\intercal$ because in that case, any matrix with all positive elements would be PSD.

Comment: Did you mean $y_i^Ty_j \leq C_{ij}$?  Are the $C_{ij}$ matrices or numbers?

Comment: For that matter, what are the $y_i$?  Are they supposed to be row-vectors or column-vectors?  Is $x$ a column-vector or a matrix of $d$ columns?

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol $[y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n]$ if the $y_i$s are vectors of different sizes?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these issues. I added detail and clarification to the post. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Yes, $y_i$s are vectors of different sizes. Thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the post to reflect this correctly. @user1551

Comment: Now what do you mean by $y_iy_j\preceq C_{ij}$, when the LHS is a $d_i\times d_j$ matrix that usually isn't square (not to say symmetric)?

Comment: Good point! $\preceq$ is not defined when $d_i \neq d_j$. I modified my question. @user1551

Comment: Why does, for example, $B = xx^T$ not work, here? What is the condition you're looking for?